# How to split a number from a given string in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have created two comboboxes. I have to create a match the following program, so that

```
function changeHandler(e:Event)
{
    trace(ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label+ComboBox(a1).selectedItem.label);
}
```

if e.target retrieves `a1`. I have to split this to `1`

Comment: use String.substr() or String.subString()

Comment: -1 for not trying something first, and for posting a question so sparse in detail.
What is the pattern for the string you are getting? Is it just 1 letter and then 1 digit, or can it be something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does work

assuming your ComboBox instance name is a0

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;
a0.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
function changeHandler(e:Event) {
    trace(e.target.selectedItem.label);
    trace(e.target.selectedItem.label.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For a general string `"a1"`:**

```
function changeHandler(e:Event)
{
    var tempStr:String = "a1";
    var intValue:int = int(tempStr.substr(1));
}
```

**For `ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label`:**

```
 function changeHandler(e:Event)
    {
        var tempStr:String = ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label;
        var intValue:int = int(tempStr.substr(1));
    }
```

Comment: `function changeHandler(e:Event)
  {
   //trace(ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label+ComboBox(a1).selectedItem.label);
   var label_:String = e.target.name;
   var item_a=ComboBox(getChildByName("a"+label_.substr(1,2))).selectedItem.label;
   var item_b = ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label;
   trace(item_a,item_b);
   if (item_a=="None")
   {
    trace("select item from list");
   }
   else if ((item_a=="Sovereign")&&(item_b=="AAA"))
   {
    Object(root).getChildByName("lb_"+label_.substr(1,2)).text="0";

   }`

Answer (score -2):

Haven't here Flash, but I think you can try

```
trace(ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.label+substring(1,ComboBox(a1).selectedItem.label));
```

does it work?

Comment: if you _don't_ know Flash then how on earth can you tell him what to do? "Does it work"?? What are you doing, answering or asking the question?

Comment: I do know Flash, I haven't Flash in this computer and I'm trying to help, if you don't like, just ignore, ok? Thanks

Comment: well, it's the wrong answer because that would not work anyway. And you should make sure it works before you post it as an "_answer_"